# An equation with angles of triangle satisfies 60 degrees triad, can we say that the triangle is equilateral?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

***Question:***

In a triangle ABC, the equation $2\cos A \sin C=\sin B $ holds true. What type of triangle is it?

Choices available are: a) isosceles b) equilateral

***Solution:***

$$2\cos A \sin C=\sin B $$
$$\Rightarrow \sin(A+C) -\sin (A-C)=\sin B$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin(A+C) -\sin (A-C)=\sin(180º - (A+C))$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin(A+C) -\sin (A-C)=\sin (A+C)$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin (A-C),  A = C$$

Hence isosceles.

**Confusion:**

But, using $A=B=C=\frac{\pi}{3}$ in the original equation, we get $2*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{\sqrt3}{2}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ which is true.

I tried to obtain a proof for both "the triangle is equilateral" and "the triangle is not equilateral", but I end in deadlock situation, so could not obtain any proof for any of the two claims.
So, just because the equation satisfies, $A=B=C=\frac{\pi}{3}$, can we say that the triangle is equilateral?

Textbook has "isosceles" as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have successfully proved that $A=C$. However, you cannot show that $A=B=C$. So the triangle cannot be shown to be equilateral. However, every equilateral triangle, also has both sides equal, so equilateral triangles also satisfy your condition. So what we have is,

Every equilateral triangle satisfies your equation, but not every triangle that satisfies your equation is equilateral, but it is definitely isosceles. So the correct answer would be isosceles.

Comment: So, logic boils down to, "If a statement is false for even one condition,and true for other conditions, then the statement is false." Here, the statement "The given equation is of equilateral triangle" is False, since (30,30,120) is well satisfied by the equation but is not an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right.

Comment: @Sahil To be accurate, the statement *"for all triangle satisfying the following formula, the triangle is equilateral"* is false, because there are counterexamples. The statement *"there exists a triangle satisfying the following formula, such that the triangle is equilateral"* is true, however. In your question, *"for all triangle"* is implied.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, yes that would be a more precise way of putting at. And hence, a better way of putting it.

Answer (score -1):

Your solution is right.

Your example is also right because an equilateral triangle is also an isosceles triangle.

Formally you can say that the triangle isosceles or equilateral, as for example, you can say that the triangle is isosceles or right-angled isosceles triangle with $\beta=90^{\circ},$ but it's better to say that the answer it's: The triangle is an isosceles triangle.

Comment: So, is the triangle isosceles or equilateral?

Comment: @Sahil The triangle is  isosceles.